# Semimartingales are closed under absolutely continuous measure change.

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am seeking a validation, correction and hopefully a reference for the following (repaired?) claim. It comes from guessing from the properties section of semimartingales at wikipedia.

Let $S$ be a $P$-semimartingale and let $M$ be a (strictly) positive, unit-initialized $P$-martingale. Let $T<\infty$.

Then if $A$ is t-measurable through $Q(A)=E[1_A M_t ]$ $M$ defines a measure change to an equivalent measure $Q$ and $S$ is also a $Q$-semimartingale. Since $1/M_T$ is trivially a $Q$-martingale going in the other directions, any $Q$-semimartingale is a $P$-semimartingale.  (<- Edit:  Last appearance there i accidently wrote $P$-martingale, thanks!)

I.e. the class of semimartingales is closed with respect to equivalent measure changes.

Edit: Limit Theorems of Stochastic Processes Theorem 3.13 appears to work.

Comment: when you go in the other direction you probably mean that you get a $P$-SEMImartingale. I guess that at least in the continuous semimartingale case you can see it as a consequence of Ito. Wlog, if $S$ is a $P$ local martingale, than $S/M$ is a $Q$ local martingale, and $d(S/M) = dS + d(1/M) + dS \cdot d(1/M).$ Leaving $dS$ on one side you get the semimartingale decomposition for it under $Q$.

Comment: @Corn Thanks! The thing is, and maybe I should have made that explicit,  that the continuous case isn't enough for me here! (And that's the problem, I have almost only studied the continuous case and don't know where to find the general stuff).